# XDK redirect to template file won't work correctly

Tags: javascript, php, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

I am trying to redirect to a template file after an Ajax call using:

```
window.location.href = "templates/somepage.html";
```

It goes to the page, however, on that page, the buttons won't load properly and the JavaScript won't get called when I click the buttons. I probably need some sort of callback because `index.html` needs to get called as well as `templates/somepage.html`.

NB: We are using the Ionic framework but I am not experienced with it, as I am a php developer. Also, I would prefer a non-jquery solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason nothing works or displays correctly because the file you are redirecting to is missing all the core include (the `CSS` and `JavaScript`) files as can be seen below:

**about.html**

This is a base `Ionic` template file and as you can see it has no `<script></script>` or `<link>` tags.

```
<ion-view title="About" id="page9">
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thus none of your `CSS` or `JavaScript` is working correctly.

`Ionic` is built on top of `AngularJS` so you can use the the state changer instead of directly accessing or redirecting to a template file as you are doing.

What you have to do is inject the `$state` in to your controller as can be seen in the example below:

**routes.js**

You should be already familiar with all of this, but you'll be referring to the state using `myView`.

```
[...].state('myView', {
    url: '/my-url',
    templateUrl: 'my/template/location.html',
    controller: 'myViewCtrl'
});
```

**controllers.js**

In your controller, you'll inject the `$state` which will be used to change the *view*.

```
[...].controller('myCtrl', function ($state) {

    /** This will be used to change to the route that we created above. **/
    $state.go('myView');

});
```

I struggled with this too when I first started using `Ionic` and I stumbled across the solution and thought I'd help out.

**Reading Material**

[Activating a State](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#activating-a-state)

[`$state.go()` Reference](http://luxiyalu.com/reference-state-go-with-parameter/)